# Rewrite assets folder from sub-domain to root domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect styles requests from subdomain to main domain

`https://dir.example.com/assets/(.*)` to `https://example.com/assets/(.*)`

I am able to successful manage this issue with subfolder via bellow code:

`example.com/dir/assets/(.*)` to `example.com/assets/(.*)`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/dir/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1
```

I tried to modify for subdomain but bellow code is **not working**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^dir.example.com/assets/(.*)$ example.com/assets/$1
```

what will be correct way of rewriting assets from sub-domain to main domain ?

Answer (score 1):

I did it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.org[NC]
RewriteRule ^/?assets/(.*)$ https://example.org/crm/assets/$1 [L,R]
```

but now i have bigger issue:

Access to font at 'https://example.org/crm/assets/plugins/roboto/fonts/Regular/Roboto-Regular.ttf?v=1.1.0' from origin 'https://crm1.example.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

### Edit

Found Solution for second issue

.htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```